# AWS PHP SDK: The logs service does not have version: latest

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to initialize an AWS PHP SDK CloudWatchLogs client object like this:

```
$client = new CloudWatchLogsClient([
    'region'    => 'ap-northeast-1',
    'version'   => '2014-03-28',
]);
```

I get an error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\Exception\UnresolvedApiException: The logs service does not have version: 2014-03-28. in /var/www/application/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/ApiProvider.php:85"
```

I get the same error if I specify 'latest' for the version.

What's going on? All the examples I found online use 'latest'. I chose that date because I found it in the [SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CloudWatchLogs.CloudWatchLogsClient.html) (see screenshot below). But I am honestly not sure if that's the date I'm supposed to use. I couldn't find any helpful information online.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade AWS SDK to solve this. Latest AWS SDK doesn't have this problem.