# Laravel - AWS SDK PHP - The logs service does not have version: latest

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-php-sdk

I'm using https://github.com/maxbanton/cwh to send logs to cloudwatch. It works locally but cloud.
This is the erro that is returning on cloud. I specified lates and 2014-03-28 version.

> laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency
> logger. {"exception":"[object]
> (Aws\Exception\UnresolvedApiException(code: 0): The logs service
> does not have version: 2014-03-28. at
> /var/www/vhosts/stage2.abalancingact.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/ApiProvider.php:85)

I checked the php and laravel version on cloud and I tried different versions of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625553/aws-php-sdk-the-logs-service-does-not-have-version-latest might be of some help

Comment: Try `'version' => '2010-08-01'`.